# GDI contents not rendered correctly using Direct2D GdiInteropRenderTarget

Tags: windows, interop, rendering, gdi, direct2d

I'm trying to render some contents using both Gdi and Direct 2D on a compatible render target. I create the compatible target with D2D1_COMPATIBLE_RENDER_TARGET_OPTIONS_GDI_COMPATIBLE option and then I do as follows:

```
    m_pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
    m_pRenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());
    m_pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));

    // Direct2D content
    D2D1_RECT_F rect1 = D2D1::RectF(50.0f, 50.0f, 200.0f, 100.0f);
    m_pRenderTarget->FillRectangle(&rect1, m_pCornflowerBlueBrush);

    // GDI content
    HDC hDC = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = m_pGDIRT->GetDC(D2D1_DC_INITIALIZE_MODE_COPY, &hDC);
    ::SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);
    ::TextOut(hDC, 30, 50, _T("stackoverflow"), 13);
    ::TextOut(hDC, 80, 70, _T("stackoverflow"), 13);
    ::TextOut(hDC, 150, 85, _T("stackoverflow"), 13);
    m_pGDIRT->ReleaseDC(NULL);

    hr = m_pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
```

I find the GDI content not rendered completely, just like it is clipped by the Direct2D content, like this:

[image]

If I don't call "m_pRenderTarget->Clear()" method, the GDI content can rendered correctly, like this:

[image]

So what's wrong with my code, how to draw Gdi content to a compatible target correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Pay close attention to the documentation and sample code at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370971(v=vs.85).aspx

In particular, you should not overlap Direct2D and GDI rendering. Call `EndDraw` *before* `GetDC`.

Comment: GetDC can be called only after BeginDraw and before EndDraw. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371323(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It is very strange that the sample code in MSDN doesn't call pRenderTarget->Clear().